# Error trying to load a package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, package, install.packages

I am trying to install the CosmoPhotoz package on a new macbook pro. I have never had an issue installing packages in R and Rstudio so I am not sure how to go about fixing this error.

```
    install.packages("CosmoPhotoz", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", 
    dependencies=TRUE)
    library(CosmoPhotoz)
```

This is the error message:

```
 Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.2.6 is being loaded, but >= 0.3 is required
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: replacing previous import by ‘grid::arrow’ when loading ‘ggthemes’ 
 2: replacing previous import by ‘grid::unit’ when loading ‘ggthemes’ 
 3: replacing previous import by ‘scales::alpha’ when loading ‘ggthemes’ 
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘CosmoPhotoz’
```

Comment: It looks like the package requires a newer version of `htmltools`. Try `update.packages()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with another package (sqldf).

Try using:

```
install.packages(htmltools)
install.packages("CosmoPhotoz")
```